# Swift Codable Parsing keyNotFound

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm having an issue getting codable going. Any help would greatly appreciated. I have the following in my playground

My JSON file

```
{
"metadata": {
  "generated": {
    "timestamp": 1549331723,
    "date": "2019-02-04 20:55:23"
  }
},
"data": {
    "CA": {
    "country-id": 25000,
    "country-iso": "CA",
    "country-eng": "Canada",
    "country-fra": "Canada"
    }
  }
}
```

I used the quicktype app to help generate the following structs

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let metadata: Metadata?
    let data: DataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let ca: CA

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ca = "CA"
    }
}

// MARK: - CA
struct CA: Codable {
    let countryID: Int
    let countryISO, countryEng, countryFra: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case countryID = "country-id"
        case countryISO = "country-iso"
        case countryEng = "country-eng"
        case countryFra = "country-fra"
    }
}

// MARK: - Metadata
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let generated: Generated?
}

// MARK: - Generated
struct Generated: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int?
    let date: String?
}
```

Swift Code:

```
 do {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") else { return 0 }

        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        let data = try decoder.decode(CA.self, from: jsonData)
        print (data)
        print(data.countryID)
        print(data.countryISO)
    } catch { print("error" , error) }
```

This is the error message I get.

```
jsonData 244 bytes
error keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "country-id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"country-id\", intValue: nil) (\"country-id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The value is there, I'm not sure what the issue is. If I take remove country-id from the json and model, I get the same error for country-iso.

Comment: `let data = try decoder.decode(CA.self, from: jsonData)` => `let data = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to decode the wrong type. The `CA` type is nested several levels in your JSON, you need to pass the root type to `JSONDecoder.decode`.

```
let root = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
guard let ca = root.data?.ca else { return 0 }
print(ca)
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I get the warning: Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any' In this case, what is Any?

Comment: @TheBear check my updated answer. You need to handle `data` being `Optional`. You get that warning, because you're printing an `Optional`.

Comment: Thanks Dávid Pásztor.

Comment: @TheBear Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).